# Sticky Footer Not Working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, sticky-footer

We've got a sticky footer that is working great in anything WebKit based but doesn't seem to work in Firefox (Or new versions of IE either).

There is extra space being generated below the footer of around 200px in height that is inheriting the background colour of body.

The extra space does not seem to be part of any div that we can find, including html, body, content, wrapper etc. etc. It also does not seem to be caused by any sort of padding or margins on any elements.

We've built it on [Ryan Fait's CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) method that uses a push div inside of the wrapper div, with a separate footer div.

You can check it out at [redesign.treepuncher.com/freetrial/](http://redesign.treepuncher.com/freetrial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframe at the bottom of your page and copyright is creating unnecessary space. You can stop iframe from being displayed if that does not affect your website's functionality.
Try this code:

```
.copy {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    margin: 95px 15px 0 15px; //Fixes margin at the bottom of this div
}

iframe {
    display: none; //Stops iframe from being displayed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following css should make it sticky and remove unnecessary space at bottom

```
.footer {
    background-color: #006837;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: "roboto",sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 100;
    height: 120px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That makes it a persistent footer, we just want a sticky footer at the bottom of the page no matter what the height of the page, or gets hidden if there is enough content to fill the full browser.

Take a look at [Ryan Fait's Example Code](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)